# Fiori Element: Checkbox in a table

Tags: sapui5

I'm working with Fiori elements, and in the ObjectPage I want to display a table inside a section. For this table I have a column as a boolean type.

Is it possible to manage this column as a checkbox by annotation, or some other way? If so, how?

Comment: Hi Joseph. Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you include some of the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it should not be possible. Since a checkbox basically has two states, it should be able to handle the boolean variables very well. Care to explain more about what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When using Fiori Elements currently a boolean value is displayed as text.
Expect you are in edit mode - then a checkbox is rendered.
So, the answer is 'No' for display mode and 'yes' (by default) for edit mode.